# addAttributeToSelect not working

Tags: magento-1.9.3.4

I am using below code to load product collection in custom module helper

```
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('custom_attribute_code')
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('status',1);
```

But `addAttributeToSelect` does not work, product collection does not include my `custom_attribute_code` attribute.

I also tried passing attributes in `array()`.

It work if I pass attribute code twice as in below code

```
->addAttributeToSelect('custom_attribute_code','custom_attribute_code')
```

Anyone know why this strange issue is happening?

Comment: try with addAttributeToSelect('*')

Comment: You want to attribute value in getData() ? if you use foreach and try get attribute value using product object them you can get it $product->getCustomAttribute();

Comment: I don't want load all attributes. anyways it does not make any difference

Comment: I think addAttributeToSelect('*')  will not display any attribute value in getData function attribute values can get by product object because it's EAV

Comment: @VaibhavAhalpara I know how to get attributes from product object, the issue here is I don't want loop product collection instead I want array of values of a particular attribute

Comment: If you use attribute filter then you can get attribute value in collection or on hard way you have to use join table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use addAttributeToSelect function it will call

```
Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract:addAttributeToSelect($attribute, $joinType = false)
```

here your second parameter will used as joinType

In addAttributeToSelect method there is a code to check if $joinType has value and attribute value is static

```
LINE 430 : if ($joinType !== false && !$this->getEntity()->getAttribute($attribute)->isStatic()) {
        $this->_addAttributeJoin($attribute, $joinType);
    }
```

Then it will call $this->_addAttributeJoin($attribute, $joinType);

```
Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract::_addAttributeJoin($attributeCode, $joinType = 'inner')
```

In this function $joinType is used as table join method

```
Line 1312 : $joinMethod = ($joinType == 'left') ? 'joinLeft' : 'join';
```

you can see here if $joinType == 'left' then it will select joinLeft else select join method

after that magento will join attribut table using above method and fetch data.

so basically you do not need to pass variable 2 times if you leave it blank then also it will works

```
    ->addAttributeToSelect('custom_attribute_code','custom_attribute_code')
```

the second attribute here is used to select table join method which is either left (joinLeft) or simple join

Comment: Yes , it should work if I leave second parameter blank, but It is not working in my case it is not working. It work if I pass second parameter (even any random value)

Comment: blank means ->addAttributeToSelect('custom_attribute',''); if you not use second parameter then it will use false

Comment: Can you tell me which magento version you have checked it

Comment: version 1.9.3.4

Comment: still leaving second parameter blank does not giving me expected output, it works when I pass null (even passing false does not work) as second parameter

Comment: false will not work have you try ->addAttributeToSelect('custom_attribute_code','') or ->addAttributeToSelect('custom_attribute_code','left')
or ->addAttributeToSelect('custom_attribute_code','join')

Comment: yes but it's not issue. second parameter is used by magento to select table join method

Answer (score 0):

do some temp filter using some non existing value, you will get that attribute into a result.

```
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
              ->addAttributeToFilter('custom_attribute_code',array('neq'=>'111');
              ->addAttributeToFilter('status',1);
```

Comment: it may work in static queries but I can not add random value filter for dynamic queries

Comment: that add not allow null filter

Answer (score 0):

You need to set store id for custom_attribute to be included in the select statement.

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                        ->setStoreId(1)
                        ->getCollection()
                        ->addAttributeToSelect(array('sku','name','custom_attribute'))
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('status',array('eq' =>1))
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_set_id','64')
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('custom_attribute',array('notnull' => true))
                        ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'ASC')
                        ->load();
```